# Math.floor(Math.random() * val.length) returns a letter not a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, math

I am trying to get a single random background image when someone visits/refreshes the page.

Writing out the array, like below, produces the desired outcome but I'd like to pull from a folder.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    var images=[
      './images/01.jpg',
      './images/02.jpg',
      './images/03.jpg',
    ];

  $('#backgroundImage').attr('src',images[randomNumber]); // Random image

});
```

Using an ajax request, as below, *almost* works except Math.floor() returns a letter or special character like

```
img alt="" id="backgroundImage" src="g"
```

and not

```
img alt="" id="backgroundImage" src="./images/02.jpg"
```

Code:

```
var images = "images/";

$.ajax({
    url : images,
    success: function (data) {
        $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
            if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) { 
               $("body").append( "<img src='" + images + val[Math.floor(Math.random() * val.length)] +"'>" );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: No, it's not returning anything but a number.

Comment: what does `data` look like when it comes back from the ajax request?

Comment: Instead of posting a question on SO, *by far* the best way to solve this problem quickly is to use the powerful debugger built into your browser to set a breakpoint on the ajax completion callback and step through the code statement by statement, looking at your variables and such as you go.

Comment: Currently you are just adding a character of the val string, `"test"[2] == "s"`

Comment: You're getting a letter because you're indexing into val

Comment: What's the goal of the code block at the end?

Comment: @KevinCollins , it returns the html markup.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , using debugger it will go through the entire images/ and return everything correctly until it gets to the **if** statement.

Comment: @bardic: And *then* what? What about when you step into the `if` block? And look at `val`? Etc., etc.? And again: What's the goal of the code at the end? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder once is gets to the **if** statement that's it, it doesn't return the values (they are correct at this point) and apply them to the "body". I want the request to return the images from the folder so I can then use math.random to pick a random image to use as the background.

Comment: @bardic: I'm quite sure it's not just suddenly stopping there (unless of course you have no `a` elements in the returned HTML with `href`s matching that regex), it may be worth spending some time getting more familiar with the use of the debugger. Meanwhile, charlietfl's answer seems to be in the region of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing right now with `val[Math.floor(Math.random() * val.length)]` is picking a random character from the string `val` (the value of the `href` attribute on the `a` element in question).

You probably want to make an array of all the images from the `<a>` then use the original code to get a random one from that array

```
var imgArray = $(data).find("a").filter(function(){
  return this.href.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/)
}).map(function(){
    return images + this.href
}).get();

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);         
$('#backgroundImage').attr('src',imgArray[randomNumber]);
```

Comment: Taken the liberty of adding the explanation of what he/she is currently doing from my (now deleted) answer to the beginning of the above.

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl very much.

Comment: It worked once I removed .map(function(){
    return images + this.href
})